# Outlook –like Context Menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, outlook, vsto

First of all please excuse my lousy English :(

I’m trying to copy the Outlook-SendTo-Context-Menu.

When you type in a EMail address, it will ShowUp and „Auto-Complete-Menu“ with an X to delete entries out of the list.

And there is my Problem, i can create a Conext Menu like:

```
foreach (string item in hist)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) continue;
    MenuItem mI = new MenuItem();
    Button mB = new Button();
    mB.Content = "X";
    mB.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItemClick_Delete);
    mI.Header = item;
    mI.Tag = item;
    mI.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItemClick_SelectFolder);
    //mI.Icon = mB;
    mB.Tag = mI;               
    // mB.IsMouseOver +=                
    //submI.Header = "Löschen";
    //submI.Tag = item;
    ///submI.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItemClick_Delete);
    cm.Items.Add(mI);
}
return cm;
```

I tryed to add a Icon/Image, but it looks ugly. Because the button is in-front of the text and not behind.

I will post you an Image of what i mean ->

[image]

Maybe there is already a Component for, or its not working like i thought.. i'm open for almost everything :)

Thanks for far!

Comment: Why you did not design your Contextmenu in Xaml and then feed it with your Data?

Comment: Oh i never did this in VS, only in Pascal , i thought there is a easier way to do so. thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Rabban You may have a hint/document for me? i found some stuff at google but it didn't serve my needs :(